# Why would you pass a reference itself?

Tags: java, this, inner-classes

I was wondering when and why would an object reference itself. I was reading inner classes using the 'this' keyword and it is a little confusing. A simple example and explanation would be great.

Comment: It's used pretty often in constructors. It assists, at the very least, with readability.

Comment: In case you need to pass around the current instance. Yes, it's that easy. The observer pattern comes to mind where sometimes you want to send along the sender (as is common in the C# `event` construct)

Comment: There are various reasons to write the `this` keyword. Do you just wonder "why would I ever do that?" or is there something about the documentation of inner classes that mentions the `this` keyword in a confusing way? If you aren't getting the answer you need, try editing the question to refer to (or show) the confusing piece of documentation.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It is simply passing current instances in order to have different functions performed on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another important reason that I don't think has been covered already (OK, I see Jeroen alluded to it in a comment):

Sometimes an object just needs to tell a method in another class about itself.  An example off the top of my head:  Say you have a `Message` abstract class with an `action()` method that performs an appropriate action for the message.  Say that there's a `MessageQueue` class that keeps track of messages that can't be acted on right away, and has other methods that later go through the queue and perform those actions that are now possible:

```
public class MessageQueue {
    public void queue(Message m) { ... }
    // other methods
}
```

A certain type of `Message` may have an `action()` method that, under certain circumstances, may want to queue itself to be called later:

```
public class MessageTypeA extends Message {

    @Override
    public void action() {
         if (webConnection.completed()) {
             // do the action
         } else {
             MessageQueue q = // find out what queue to put myself on
             q.queue(this);   // ********* HERE *********
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is actually what i was referring to. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

It is used when you want to refer to an instance method or variable in the same object, for example in constructors, in order to distinguish the parameters from the instance variables

```
class MyClass {

     private int valueA;
     private int valueB;

     public MyClass(int valueA, int valueB) {
         this.valueA = valueA;
         this.valueB = valueB;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
class MyClass {
    private int myvar = 1;

    public int returnMyVar() {
        int myvar = 2;
        // return myvar;
        // or
        // return this.myvar;
    }
}
```

The myvar local variable that is declared inside the returnMyVar method masks MyClass.myvar, so if I were to uncomment the first return, 2 would be returned.  If I uncommented the second return, 1 would be returned, because we are referring to the myvar field of this class.

This is frequently seen in constructors and setters, where the parameter is often given the same name as the field they are populating.

```
public void setMyVar(int myvar) {
    this.myvar = myvar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One use of `this` is to prevent something called "variable shadowing." Basically, when a variable is declared in different scopes, it can't be determined which variable to which you are referring.

For example:

```
public class Person{
  private String name = "Defaulty McDefaultinstein";

  public void setName(String name){
    name = name;
  } 
}
```

in this case, how are we to know (on line 5) which name should be set to which name?

If we change to this:

```
public class Person{
  private String name = "Defaulty McDefaultinstein";

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

We explicitly say that the name *that belongs to the class* should be set to the name *passed to the method*, and now it's all gravy.

Answer (score 1):

Typical uses of the this keyword are [two](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

-Because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

```
public class Point {
  public int x = 0;
  public int y = 0;

  //constructor
  public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y; 
  }
}
```

-To call another constructor in the same class.

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

There is an additional reason, readability.

But also, it is quite handy when you implement the [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html), as you might need to return the object itself.

```
public class PersonBuilder
{
   private String newLastName;
   private String newFirstName;
   private String newMiddleName;

   public PersonBuilder()
   {
   }

   public PersonBuilder setNewLastName(String newLastName) {
      this.newLastName = newLastName;
      return this;
   }

   public PersonBuilder setNewFirstName(String newFirstName) {
      this.newFirstName = newFirstName;
      return this;
   }

   public PersonBuilder setNewMiddleName(String newMiddleName) {
      this.newMiddleName = newMiddleName;
      return this;
   }


   public Person createPerson() {
      return new Person(newLastName, newFirstName, newMiddleName);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.